# How to resolve issues when getting error: Not in scope

Tags: haskell, emacs, haskell-platform, haskell-mode, haskell-prelude

```
*Main> :t putStrn

<interactive>:1:1:
Not in scope: `putStrn'
Perhaps you meant one of these:  
  `putStr' (imported from Prelude),  
  `putStrLn' (imported from Prelude)
```

Please note that I am practising haskell programming in emacs with haskell mode.

Even while using terminal, I am getting following error:

```
optimight@optimight:~$ ghci  
GHCi, version 7.4.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help  
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done. 
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.  
Loading package base ... linking ... done.  
Prelude> :set prompt ghci>  
ghci>:t putStrln   

<interactive>:1:1:  
    Not in scope: `putStrln'  
    Perhaps you meant one of these:  
      `putStrLn' (imported from Prelude),  
      `putStr' (imported from Prelude)
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a function named `putStrn`?

Comment: @Pikaurd: Yes, I am using after refering to the book- Learn you a Haskell for Good - topic 9.1 where it has written "Let's examine what we wrote. First, let's look at the type of the function putStrLn.
ghci> :t putStrLn
putStrLn :: String -> IO ()
ghci> :t putStrLn "hello, world"
putStrLn "hello, world" :: IO ()

Comment: `putStrn` and `putStrln` are a different names than `putStrLn`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The I/O action you are looking for is [`putStrLn`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskell2010/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3aputStrLn). Note the capital L — Haskell symbols are case-sensitive — just before the final n, as in “put a string on a *line* of its own.”.